# Minimize $152207x-81103y$ over the positive integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, linear-diophantine-equations

> Minimize the expression $152207x-81103y$ over the positive integers,
>   given $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}.$

So the book takes me through modular arithmetic and how to find $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ in order to solve diophantine equations. Then this question pops up in the same chapter.

I know how calculate using modular arithmetic, I know how to find $\text{gcd}(a,b)$ and solve diophantine equations but I don't know how to bunch them up together in order to solve this.

How should I think?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: It is $$71104$$ for $$x=1,y=1$$

Comment: The minimum positive value of $ax+by,x,y\in\Bbb Z$ **is** $(a,b)$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown - Yeah I visited that link too before I posted here, I did not figure out how to use that information.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner - $x=2$ and $y=3$ gives $61105<71104$. So that can't be if I'm not misstaken.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri - How is $(a,b)$ a "value"?

Comment: It denotes the GCD of $a,b$

Comment: The Euclidean method for computing $\gcd (a,b)$ implicitly includes an algorithm for finding $x,y$ such that $ax+by=gcd(a,b).$  For this Q it suffices to know that such $x,y$ exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\gcd (152207,81103)=1111$ it is the same as minimum of $$1111(137x-73y)$$

Since $137x-73y=1$ is solvable (say $x=8$ and $y=15$) the answer is $1111$.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please elaborate on why we need to set the expression $137x-73y$ equal to $1$ and determine its solveability?

Comment: Ok I think I get it. It's because $=1$ gives the smallest positive integer.

Answer (score 4):

Note $c=ax+by$ has integer solution if and only if $gcd(a,b)|c$ and if this exists then infinite no of integer solutions can be obtained from 1 solution by

$x=x_{0}+\frac{b}{d}k$ and $y=y_{0}-\frac{a}{d}k$

where $d$ is the gcd.
And $x_{0},y_{0}$ are one solution which can be obtained from euclid's algorithm. (As will jagy has mentioned)

And also the defination of $gcd(a,b)$ is least positive value of the $ax+by=d$  where $x,y$ any integer.

Answer (score 2):

$$  \gcd( 152207, 81103 ) = ???    $$

$$ \frac{ 152207 }{ 81103 } = 1 +  \frac{ 71104 }{ 81103 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 81103 }{ 71104 } = 1 +  \frac{ 9999 }{ 71104 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 71104 }{ 9999 } = 7 +  \frac{ 1111 }{ 9999 } $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 9999 }{ 1111 } = 9 +  \frac{ 0 }{ 1111 } $$ 
 Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 & & 1 & & 1 & & 7 & & 9 & \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 1 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 2 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 15 }{ 8 }   & &   \frac{ 137 }{ 73 }  
 \end{array}
 $$ 
 $$  $$ 
 $$ 137 \cdot 8 - 73 \cdot 15 = 1 $$

$$  \gcd( 152207, 81103 ) = 1111  $$
 $$ 152207 \cdot 8 - 81103 \cdot 15 = 1111 $$

Comment: Can you please explain the continued fraction part?

Comment: @Parseval you just start with the formal "fractions" $\frac{0}{1}$ and $\frac{1}{0},$ which just serve to start the process and mean nothing in themselves. Then for each "partial quotient" $d=1,1,7,9$ you just update the numerator by $n_j + d \cdot n_{j+1} = n_{j+2}.$ Similar for denominator. The usefulness for this problem is that the little 2 by 2 cross products are $\pm 1$ For example $2 \cdot 8 - 15 \cdot 1 = 1$

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. OP says they already know how to compute the gcd. They need to know how to go from that to a solution of the stated problem, not another way to compute the (extended) gcd.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have have answered.  But the thing to take away from this is the idea of [*Bezout's Lemma* (sometimes  known as *Bezout's Identity*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity).

> If $M,N$ are integers with greatest common divisor $\gcd(M,N)$ then there will exist integers $a,b$ so that $Ma + Nb = \gcd(M,N)$.

Another way of putting this is

> If $j,k$ are relatively prime integers, then there will exist integers $a,b$ so that $ja + kb = 1$.

If we note that $\gcd(M,N)|M$ and $\gcd(M,N)$ then $\gcd(M,N)|Ma + Nb$ for any integers $a,b$ which leads to a third way of putting this

> (Version 3)  If $M,N$ are integers then:
>
> 1. For any integers $a,b$ the $Ma + Nb$ will be a multiple of $\gcd(M,N)$.
> 2. Integers $c,d$ exist so that $Mc + Nd = \gcd(M,N)$.
>
> and therefore
>
> 3. For any multiple of $\gcd(M,N)$, say $k\gcd(M,N)$ for some integer $k$, then integers $a,b$ exists so that $Ma + Nb = k\gcd(M,N)$. (Just let $a = kc; b=kd$ where $c,d$ are as in 2. above.)

And this answers your question.

1. $152207x−81103y$ will always be a multiple of $\gcd(152207, 81103) = 1111$
2. $152207x - 81103y = 1111$ will be possible.

And as the smallest positive integer that is a multiple of $1111$ is $1111$, the smallest positive value of $152207x -88103y$ is $1111$.

Notice, we don't have to actually *find* the values that make this true.  It's enough to know it can be done!

====

Addendum:

1) Note: I never said and never implied that any of those integer pairs were *unique*.

$Ma + Nb = k\gcd(M,N)$ will actually have an *infinite* number of solutions.

Notice $M(a \pm w\frac N{\gcd(M,N}) + N(b \mp w\frac M{\gcd(M,N)}) = Ma + Nb = k\gcd(M,N)$ will always be a solution.  But all solutions will be is such a form.

2) To actually *find* a solution

$152207x -88103y =1111$ we can use Euclid Algorithm

$152207 = 81103 + 71104; 71104 = 152207 - 81103$

$81103 = 71104 + 9999; 9999 = 81103 - 71104 = 81103 -(152207-81103) = 2*81103-152207$

$71104 = 7*9999 + 1111; 1111 = 71104 - 7*9999=(152207 - 81103)-7(2*81103-152207)=8*152207- 15*81103$

$9999 = 9*1111 + 0$ thats as far as we can go.

So for $x = 8; y = -15$ we get $152207x+81103y = \gcd(152207, 81103)$.